# How to delete my account on icloud.com?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

In my case, I do not want to use iCloud anymore. So I don't want to sync notes, calendar, pics across my Apple devices, and access them through the web (i.e., icloud.com).

So, how I can close/delete my entire iCloud account, associated with my Apple ID? I just want to use my AppleID for the App store.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to have happen? There's no commonly known way to actually delete an Apple ID and iCloud and certainly no direct self-service way to delete an account. iCloud is many services bundled into a marketing name.

Comment: Well there is an icloud.com, and I can use my AppleID there. I just don't want to have an account on the icloud.com. Added all  these with an explanation to my question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://justdelete.me/

Comment: http://justdelete.me/#icloud gives nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the iCloud preferences and uncheck any of the iCloud services you no longer wish to use.

Do this for all your iCloud enabled devices.

The account will still exist, but will no longer be used.

Comment: The OP asks "how can I close/delete my account", this does not answer that question. I want to know exactly that.

Comment: No, OP still want's to use his Apple ID, just doesn't want to use any iCloud services, therefore account is not deleted.

Answer (score 8):

You can't remove iCloud from your Apple ID. The best you can do is clear information from it and not enable the iCloud services on your devices.